# Simplify multiple if-else statements for unit testing

Tags: java, if-statement

I am writing some java code to check multiple conditions by if-else. The code is working properly but it is hard to do unit test.

reads lines that contains keyword `conditionOne`, `conditionTwo` or other keywords. `hasConditionOneEnabled` and `hasConditionTwoEnabled` are boolean values.

My real code has more `else if` statements than the provide example.
Can anyone help? Or give me some hint how to make the code shorter then I can write unit test easier? Thanks

```
boolean a = false;
boolean b = false;


if(line.contains("conditionOne")){
    if(hasConditionOneEnabled){
        a = true;
    }else{
        b = true;
    }
}else if (line.contains("conditionTwo")){
    if(hasConditionTwoEnabled){
        a = true;
    }else{
        b = true;
    }
}else{
    a = true;
    b = true;
}


if(a && b){
    // do something 1
}else if(!a && b){
    // do something 2
}else if(a && !b){
    // do something 3
}else{
    //both false, do nothing
}
```

Comment: Overly complex conditional statements are an [anti-pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern).  Also see [this question on refactoring it away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105602/need-refactoring-ideas-for-arrow-anti-pattern).

Comment: Create a class with a and b and extract the conditions bodies as separate methods..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a and b cannot be both false after the set of if-else statements. 
In the first two if's variable a will have the same value than the corresponding hasConditionXXEnabled and b will be set as the opposite. The default else will set both to true.

Consider the following code:

```
a = true;
b = true;

if(line.contains("conditionOne")){
    a = hasConditionOneEnabled;
    b = !a;
}
else if(line.contains("conditionTwo")){
    a = hasConditionTwoEnabled;
    b = !a;
}

if(a && b){        
    // do something 1
}
else if(b){
    // do something 2
}
else{
    // do something 3
}
```

Comment: good job. the next step would be to give meaningful names to `a` and `b` or replace those flags with enum which gives a meaningful name to combinations of those flags.

Answer (score 0):

```
// test it on different line String input and different int value returned...
int xxx(String line) {
    if(line.contains("conditionOne")){
        status = hasConditionOneEnabled?0:1;
    } else if (line.contains("conditionTwo")){
        status = hasConditionTwoEnabled?0:1;
    } else{
        status = -1;
    }

    return status;
}


// test it base on different status value..
switch (status) {
case 0: ...;
case 1: ...;
default: ...;
}
```

However, if your if-else pattern can be continuously repeat after some modification, you may just create different boolean funciton for it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all both `a` and `b` **can never be false**, so your last `else` statement is redundant.

Your entire set of conditional statements can be reduced to an `if - else if - else` block. You **don't need variables `a` and `b`** since you are using them to do something else anyway. Besides vague variables names like `a` and `b` hinder readability.

Let me first show you the code and I'll walk you through it subsequently.

```
boolean lineContainsCond1 = line.contains("conditionOne");
boolean lineContainsCond2 = line.contains("conditionTwo");

boolean lineContainsNeitherCondition = !lineContainsCond1  && !lineContainsCond2;       

boolean conditionsForSomething3 = (lineContainsCond1 && conditionOneEnabled) || (lineContainsCond2 && conditionTwoEnabled);

if(lineContainsNeitherCondition)
    //do something 1 (Note: this is the same something 1 from your code)
else if(conditionsForSomething3)
    //do something 3
else
    //do something 2
```

`lineContainsNeitherCondition` is essentially both `a` and `b` being `true` in your code.

`conditionsForSomething3` tantamounts to `a!b`.

If **both  `lineContainsNeitherCondition` and `conditionsForSomething3` are `false`**, we can derive the following conclusions:

- Given `lineContainsNeitherCondition` is `false`, either `lineContainsCond1` is `true` or `lineContainsCond2` is `true`
- Case 1 : `lineContainsCond1` is `true`:
  In this case, either `conditionOneIsEnabled` is `true` or `conditionOneEnabled` is `false`. If it were `true`, then `conditionFOrSomething3` cannot be `false`, if it's `false`, then that leads to `lineContainsCond && !conditionOneEnabled` to be `true` which leads to `b!a` in the original code and thereby executes `//something 2`.

A similar argument can be made for Case 2 : `lineContainsCond2` is `true`.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't reduce the amount of if else statements in your code.

Try replacing the if else statements with private methods that return a boolean. Try to in cooperate the below methods or similar methods into your above code.

Having a look at mookito great for mocking and stubbing. If you have a big project with lots of Objects will save you hours maybe days.

```
private boolean doesLineContainCondition(String line, String  searchPhrase) {
 if(line.contains(searchPhrase) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}


private boolean hasConditionBeenEnabled(boolean condition) {
 if(condition) { 
   a = true;
  }
 else {
  b= true;
 }
}
```